# Time and Work Problem : Variable time spent by people on a work

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

> **$A, B \text{ and } C$ started working together on a project, but $A$ left the work $9$ days before the completion and $B$ left the work $7$
> days before completion. Had $A$ worked for one more day, the work
> would have been completed two days before the actual time. Had $B$
> worked for two days more, the work would have been completed three
> days before the actual time. In how many days can $A, B \text{ and}$
> $C$ together do a different work which can be done by $C$ alone in $18$
> days?**

Let in the first case the total number of days taken be $t$ days.Let the number of days taken by $A, B \text{ and } C$ to complete the work individually be  $a, b \text{ and } c$ respectively.

As per the question ; 
$\frac{t-9}{a}+\frac{t-7}{b}+\frac{t}{c}=1$

I am getting stuck after this as to how to form the equation for the other cases. In the second case (where $A$ worked for one more day), the number of days will be $t-2$ days. Now the equation should be like ;

$\frac{p}{a}+\frac{q}{b}+\frac{t-2}{c}=1$ and I am not able to figure out what should be the values for $p$ and $q$ in the equation.

Also how to create the equation for the $3rd$ case where $B$ worked for two more days.

Please help me resolve this problem!!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  when $A$ works one day more, he works $t-8$ days.  How many days do $B$ and $C$ work in the second case?

Comment: Earlier $A$ worked $t-9$ days, so it seems that if he worked one day extra that means $t-9+1 = t-8$. <br>I assume that's how you came to $t-8$ days for $A$.
For $C$ it would be $t-2$ days. <br>
For $B$ it should be $t-7-2 = t-5$ days, am I right?

Comment: Except that $t-7-2=t-9$ you are